# Can we not backpropagate model

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, training, backpropagation

I saw a model based on CNN for question classification. The author said that they don't backpropagate gradient to embeddings. How this is possible to update network if you don't backpropagate please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are using pretrained embeddings as model inputs sometimes we dont want to update embedding so thats why we don't backpropogate gradients to embeddings

Comment: Thank you. So we update the first hidden later them and all other hidden layers but not the embeddings input? Usually, we don't update the input anyway as I understand it as we just update weights and biases between input and last layer, please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: This is right, most languages allow to make embeddings untrainable of needed

Comment: Thank you. So we don't update the weights that go off from input layer but we update all other layer weights?